# Why dependencies are not added to classpath when I run spring boot project in IntellJ IDEA?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

My OS is `Ubuntu 16.04`，IDE is `IntellJ IDEA` 2018.1.3.

Recently I try to run a simple `Spring Boot` project in `Maven`, but when I run this application, I get some error messages that the dependencies does not exist, which are as follow:
[image]

I guess dependencies haven't added to classpath, but project configuration and maven dependencies are normal. I try to run the same project in other computer that OS is `Windows 10`. It works well.

- Maven:

[image]

- Project Structure:

[image]

My `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>test1</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <mysql.version>5.1.43</mysql.version>
</properties>


<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.41</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Did you create the project using `Spring Initializr` ? That happens when you create a maven project and add all `spring` dependencies. I am also using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @SAM No, I create a Empty Project at first, then add new maven module in project structure.

Comment: This is why you are facing the issue. But you can also continue with that let me post you a screen shot.

Comment: @SAM I used Spring Initializr, but it is still report those error.

Comment: see my update...

Comment: You need to add the Spring Boot Maven plugin.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes, I had tried spring boot maven plugin and runned successfully by `spring-boot:run`. But I want to run project by `Run Configuration` in IDEA.

Comment: Add a Spring Boot configuration from the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just delete the directory of `idea.system.path` in `idea/bin/idea.properties` file.

Delete `.idea/` and `*.iml` file, then reimport project.

However I still not know the cause of this problem and solution.

Comment: @AnandVarkeyPhilips yes, I have set it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following procedure is for solving the `library not found` error for projects created through `Maven Project`. But if you create a project using `Spring Initializr` then such problem won't exist. Now open `Project Structure` (shortcut Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S) in `Intellij`. Then follow this image:

[image]

Click on `Create Artifact`. Then Follow this Image:

[image]

Select all the libraries, then right-click, then select `Put into /WEB_INF/lib`. Click on OK then compile, then everything will fine. But remember to repeat the process for every newly added library. Sad but true there is no automated process for `maven project` but you can switch to `Spring Initializr`.

**UPDATE**

If you have created your project via `Spring Initializr` then i doubt that you might be using your default `Tomcat` installed on your system. In that case, you should use the `embedded tomcat` which is automatically managed by the IDE when you run it. The maven dependency link is below, and remove the tomcat configuration you previously added:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.13.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If you find the solution helpful then accept the answer as solution. Happy Coding !!!

Comment: All right, but all libraries are always palced in `/WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: Yes but not in your output folder. You need to do like it is being described in the image so that the libraries are available in the output too.

Comment: OK, I understand what you mean. But when I created project, I added `<packaging>war</packaging>` to my `pom.xml`. So libraries are intact under `/WEB-INF/lib` in `war exploded` of `Artifacts`.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion?

Comment: update your question with your contents in your `pom.xml` file and `application.properties` file, and screenshot of your `tomcat` configuration.

Comment: This is the simplest `Spring Boot` project. I have not configured `application.properties` and `tomcat`

Comment: Then you should configure that too. See `Spring Initializer` on the libraries you need. And then update you question.

Comment: I solved this problem and add answer, but I still not know the cause of this problem and solution. Also thank you for your help.

Comment: This didn't happened in my case. I too moved my project from windows 10 to ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Might be a hidden bug